# Can I mount a file system read-only into an LXC container?

Tags: linux, lxc, linux-containers

I'm working on a software built on top of LXC. Among other things, we want to mount folders from the host into the LXC container at runtime, so we can't put our mount points into our `lxc.conf` (which we do for the static mount points).

While mounting works, re-mounting read-only does not work. The re-mount succeeds in the host, but the mount-point still shows up as read/write in the container.

## Example program

I've created a small program extending the LXC API example (https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/documentation/) that shows this behaviour. I hope you'll forgive the lack of awesomeness in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                       
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <lxc/lxccontainer.h>

int do_unmount(char *dir) {
    printf("Un-mounting %s\n", dir);
    if(umount(dir) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to unmount %s\n", dir);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int container_test(struct lxc_container *c, char *mountName) {

    if (c->is_defined(c)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Container already exists\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Container now exists, good\n");
    }

    /* Create the container */
    if (!c->createl(c, "busybox", NULL, NULL, LXC_CREATE_QUIET, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create container rootfs\n");
        return 2;
    } else {
        printf("Created container rootfs\n");
    }

    /* Start the container */
    if (!c->start(c, 0, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to start the container\n");
        return 3;
    } else {
        printf("Started the container\n");
    }

    /* Query some information */
    printf("Container state: %s\n", c->state(c));
    printf("Container PID: %d\n", c->init_pid(c));

    char *rootfs = c->get_running_config_item(c, "lxc.rootfs");
    printf("Container rootfs: %s\n", rootfs);

    // Set up mount point directory
    const char *mount_relative_dir = "/mount_test";
    size_t rootfs_path_size = strlen(rootfs);
    size_t relative_dir_size = strlen(mount_relative_dir);

    char mount_dir[rootfs_path_size + relative_dir_size + 1];
    strncpy(mount_dir, rootfs, rootfs_path_size + 1);
    strcat(mount_dir, mount_relative_dir);

    // Create the mount point directory
    int dir_status = mkdir(mount_dir, S_IRWXU);
    if (dir_status == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create directory %s, error: %s\n", mount_dir, strerror(errno));
    }

    printf("Going to mount into: %s\n", mount_dir);
    if (mount(".", mount_dir, NULL, MS_BIND, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to mount ./ into %s\n", mount_dir);
        do_unmount(mount_dir);
        return 4;
    }

    printf("Going to re-mount %s read-only\n", mount_dir);
    if (mount(NULL, mount_dir, NULL, MS_BIND | MS_REMOUNT | MS_RDONLY, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to re-mount %s read-only\n", mount_dir);
        do_unmount(mount_dir);
        return 5;
    }

    /* Check the mount point from within the container */
    system("lxc-attach -n apicontainer -- /bin/ls -ahl /");
    system("lxc-attach -n apicontainer -- /bin/mount");

    /* We are done with the mount stuff now */
    do_unmount(mount_dir);
    /*  Has to be freed, allocated by LXC */
    free(rootfs);

    printf("Stopping the container\n");
    /* Stop the container */
    if (!c->shutdown(c, 30)) {
        printf("Failed to cleanly shutdown the container, forcing.\n");
        if (!c->stop(c)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to kill the container.\n");
            return 6;
        }
    }

    printf("Destroying the container\n");
    /* Destroy the container */
    if (!c->destroy(c)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to destroy the container.\n");
        return 7;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct lxc_container *c;

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <source> \n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }


    /* Setup container struct */
    c = lxc_container_new("apicontainer", NULL);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to setup lxc_container struct\n");
    } else {
        printf("Created lxc_container struct\n");
    }

    char *source_dir = argv[1];
    int status = container_test(c, source_dir);
    if(status != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** Container test FAILED with status %i ***\n", status);
    }

    lxc_container_put(c);
}
```

## Running the example

I've added some newlines and comments for readability.

```
➜  mount-test git:(master) ✗ gcc -o mount-test -llxc -g main.c 
➜  mount-test git:(master) ✗ sudo ./mount-test ./
Created lxc_container struct
Container now exists, good
Created container rootfs
Started the container
Container state: RUNNING
Container PID: 27763
Container rootfs: /var/lib/lxc/apicontainer/rootfs
Going to mount into: /var/lib/lxc/apicontainer/rootfs/mount_test
Going to re-mount /var/lib/lxc/apicontainer/rootfs/mount_test read-only
```

Output from ls -ahl / inside the container

```
total 60
drwxr-xr-x   18 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 .
drwxr-xr-x   18 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 bin
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root         340 Jun 30 10:55 dev
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 home
drwxr-xr-x   25 root     root        4.0K Jun  8 18:26 lib
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K May 31 08:42 lib64
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 mnt
drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     1000        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 mount_test
dr-xr-xr-x  300 root     root           0 Jun 30 10:55 proc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 root
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 sbin
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 selinux
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root     root           0 Jun 30 10:55 sys
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 usr
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Jun 30 10:55 var
```

Output from /bin/mount inside the container

```
/dev/md0 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=256,data=ordered)
*snip*
/dev/md0 on /mount_test type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=256,data=ordered)

Un-mounting /var/lib/lxc/apicontainer/rootfs/mount_test
Stopping the container
Destroying the container
```

So the mount succeeds, but as seen above it still shows as `rw` in the container. It shows up as read-only in my host system, however.

## Semi-solutions

I know I can of course have the mountpoint re-mounted from inside the container if needed, but I would rather have the container user not have mount privileges for security reasons (otherwise the user can re-mount existing read-only mounts to rw and modify files on the host)

Comment: FYI: We've gone with the listed semi-solution currently, remounting from inside the container.